# When tangent line doesn't exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, tangent-line

Suppose I have a parametric equation $x(t)=t^3$, $y(t)=\sin(t)$.

Then, $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\cos(t)}{3t^2}$$
At $t=0$ derivative doesn't exist. So, let's take a limit: $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\cos(t)}{3t^2}=\infty$. So, there is a vertical tangent line at $t=0$.

Now, suppose I have a parametric equation $x(t)=t^3$, $y(t)=\cos(t)$.

Then, $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-\sin(t)}{3t^2}$$
At $t=0$ derivative doesn't exist. So, let's take a limit: $\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{-\sin(t)}{3t^2}=-\infty$, $\lim_{t\to 0^-}\frac{-\sin(t)}{3t^2}=\infty$. Since the limit doesn't exist, then there is no vertical tangent line at $t=0$.

Now, consider the polar curve $r(\theta)=\cos(\theta)$.
Then, $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\cot(2\theta)$$

Clearly, the limit doesn't exist at $\theta=0$, but tangent line exists and it equals $x=1$.

I thought that if limit exists and finite, then this is the "normal" case, if limit exists and infinite, then there is a vertical tangent line, if it doesn't exist, then there is no tangent line.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: In the case of $y'=-\cot2\theta$, the limit doesn't exist because the one-sided limits disagree: $+\infty$ & $-\infty$. But, as *slopes*, $+\infty$ & $-\infty$ both correspond to a vertical line, which is consistent w/the vertical tangent for $\theta=0$; this is something of a special case. ... In the context of parametric eqns, it's often a good idea to leverage the separation of $x$ & $y$ components and talk about tangent *vectors*, which allow either component to vanish with impunity. In the first example, the tangent vector $(3t^2,\cos t)$ at $t=0$ is $(0,1)$: uncontroversially vertical.

Comment: Your limits are wrong.

Comment: @aarbee , what exactly is wrong?

Comment: You can either use series expansion or L'Hopital to get to the answer.

Comment: The tangent line of both paths $(t^3,\sin(t))$ and $(t^3,\cos(t))$ exist in $t=0$.

Comment: Where did you get this rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the curve parameterized by $x(t) = \sin(t),$ $y(t) = t^3.$
For this curve, $\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = \dfrac{3t^2}{\cos(t)},$ and

$$ \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{3t^2}{\cos(t)} = 0, $$

so by the rules you've given, you have a horizontal tangent at $t=0.$

But the curve is an exact image of the one parameterized by
$x(t) = t^3,$ $y(t) = \sin(t)$ under reflection through the line $y = x.$
In parametric curves like these, we care about the geometric shape, not whether the curve can be described by $y$ as a function of $x.$
A horizontal tangent at $t=0$ on one curve ought to correspond to a vertical tangent on the other.

Another way to look at the curve $x(t) = t^3,$ $y(t) = \sin(t)$ is:

$$ \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy}
 = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{3t^2}{\cos(t)}= 0. $$

But note that this rule cannot distinguish when a curve has a cusp.
If you're concerned about that, you might want to use tangent vectors rather than tangent lines.